# Find and click the button Java Robot

Tags: java, click, find, element, awtrobot

How can I click on this button by using Java Robot Class? Or maybe there is any better way to do that? This button is from external Windows program, and the button is from QT5 library as i know so I guess I must just simulate a mouse to click that if i want make it run right? I tried to find that pixel by pixel but its still so hard to me, Im sure i saw somewhere solution to do that but cant find it from few hours...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll most likely need to use the JNI.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface